# How to execute second jQuery snippet to add html code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to remove all class that have icons on them. Also, I'd like to replace their HTML code.

There is `.icon-eye-open` that got font awesome icon on it, i want to change it for twitter heart snippet.

I managed to remove class, so i have empty space to add html code but i stuck in choosing the way how to. I googled a lot of diffrent ways, but the jQuery looks the easiest to fire off, but apparently its not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.visible-desktop').after('<a href="/basketedit.php?mode=2"><input id="toggle-heart" type="checkbox"/><label for="toggle-heart">❤</label></a>');
});
```

The point is that i can't touch HTML or parcial css.
Codepen:
https://codepen.io/graphconcept/pen/vwNNwQ

Comment: Make the `$('.visible-desktop').after('<a href="/basketedit.php?mode=2"><input id="toggle-heart" type="checkbox"/>
<label for="toggle-heart">❤</label></a>');` in one line (there's a -enter- after the checkbox-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is the same as what's in your script, JS does not go well with litteral linebreaks in strings;

You'll have to escape the linebreak

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.visible-desktop').after('<a href="/basketedit.php?mode=2"><input id="toggle-heart" type="checkbox"/> \
    <label for="toggle-heart">❤</label></a>');
});
```

-OR-
Concatenate the 2 strings

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.visible-desktop').after('<a href="/basketedit.php?mode=2"><input id="toggle-heart" type="checkbox"/>' +
    '<label for="toggle-heart">❤</label></a>');
});
```

-OR-
Like Roy said in the comments, remove the break.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.visible-desktop').after('<a href="/basketedit.php?mode=2"><input id="toggle-heart" type="checkbox"/> <label for="toggle-heart">❤</label></a>');
});
```